# What are the benefits of XSL over standard MVC3 Views syntax?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, xslt

I'm working on an existing MVC3 application. Usually when working on MVC3 projects I expect to see HTML & MVC3 markup in the Views (`.cshtml`).

However, with this application, each view only has a call to `XSLTEngine.Raw()`. Looking through this code this is making calls to XSL files which contain an XML-like syntax containing elements which appear to be rendered as HTML (Presumably by the `XSLTEngine.Raw()` method).

What are the benefits of storing this content in XSL files instead of HTML/MVC3 syntax within the View file?

Comment: You can use the XML data for more than just the web UI?

Comment: The usual benefit is that an Architect has been able to charge outrageous consultancy fees for a very long time. Oh, you meant benefits to the *application*? I don't know then ;)

Comment: @Oded I believe the application is using XML data. However, I don't understand how using XSL files allows you to use the XML data for more than just the web UI. Surely this can be done anyway from the Controller?

Comment: Frankly, there isn't enough context to determine why. Where is the XSLT get XML data to transform to HTML from? Is this XML used elsewhere? Does it come from legacy systems?

Comment: @Oded Cheers for your response. To be honest I'm not 100% sure at the moment. Are you suggesting this method is only used so that the application can easily use old data? I think a previous version of the application was developed in Classic ASP.

Comment: The XSL files are a UI concern - they transform the XML to HTML. How would you go about doing that with normal view constructs? How would you use XML directly in a view?

Comment: That is entirely possible, in particular if the developers didn't want to change the data access layer (so in this case MVC is simply putting lipstick on a pig). I have seen Classic ASP using XML as a data layer (badly) in the past, so, simply reusing the data layer cuts costs and speeds up development.

Comment: @Oded `How would you use XML directly in a view` My point is I wouldn't store the HTML markup in XML in the first place. If I had just data stored in XML then i would probably convert this datasource into a `List` at controller level, so that I can loop through the data at View level.

Comment: That's kinda my point. You would need an extra step of converting to a model. With XSLT, you skip that (and reuse the existing XSLT...). Again - this sounds like a _shortcut_ to moving to MVC, without using the MVC framework...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a port of an older application that used XML as a data source, the easiest thing to do in order to convert to MVC is to reuse the XML data and transform it using XSLT.

To be honest, it makes little sense to port such an application *at all* (as essentially, it is the *same* application on a different framework), unless one can't find developers conversant in the older technology anymore.

Comment: Thanks Oded, could there be any performance advantage to using XSL over standard HTML / Razor?

Comment: @Curt - I wouldn't expect there to be. This is an extra step and XSLT is CPU intensive.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped clear up my confusion of the use of XSL. I was starting to question whether my studying of MVC3 Razor controls had already become deprecated!

Answer (score 4):

Hard to tell. The application might be doing a job for which XSLT is uniquely well suited (it's a language that is optimized for certain tasks); or it might be reusing code that already existed in XSLT; or it might have been written by someone who had skills in XSLT and didn't have time to learn a different technology; or it might have been written by someone with a religious attachment to XSLT (lots of programmers have religious attachments to particular programming languages, by which I mean they choose it on aesthetic rather than scientific criteria; XSLT is no exception).

These are pretty well the same answers as you would get to any question of the form "Why is X written in L?" where X is a software component and L is a programming language.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Theres no particular reason why XSLT should be preferenced over standard MVC3/Razor techniques then

Comment: Your use of the word "standard" seems to be prejudging the answer. I would want to look at the job that the code is doing. There are definitely some tasks where XSLT is a better approach than any other. There are other tasks where it isn't.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm fairly new to MVC3 and any examples I've seen of it have always used Razor and HTML markup hence my use of the word "standard". However, since, I've been doing more research on XSLT and would be grateful for any useful tutorials or documents which may help me better understand the syntax

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the aim is to provide a wider support for end client platforms/devices?

Although you might not be using the traditional MVC features you are used to, you do get the use of controllers still - which is my opinion is very tidy and makes it easy to work with (and organise) page requests/responses. Not to mention the great built-in support for parameter mapping (and potentially model binding, but not sure how/if that would work with your XSL)

Just had a quick look through [this short presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/nikkimk/xslt-what-is-it-and-why-use-it-presentation) and it highlights some key benefits of XSLT over HTML - check it out!

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link! I've been looking all day for something like this!